# Tell which is pressed using Array of ImageButtons

Tags: java, android, arraylist, imagebutton

I have a basic hangman game, and the buttons to make the guesses are all placed on screen with ImageButtons (I had this working perfectly).

I declare the image button ID's like so:

```
    private static final int[] BUTTON_IDS = {
        R.id.imageButtonA, R.id.imageButtonB, R.id.imageButtonC, R.id.imageButtonD, R.id.imageButtonE,
        R.id.imageButtonF, R.id.imageButtonG, R.id.imageButtonH, R.id.imageButtonI, R.id.imageButtonJ,
        R.id.imageButtonK, R.id.imageButtonL, R.id.imageButtonM, R.id.imageButtonN, R.id.imageButtonO,
        R.id.imageButtonP, R.id.imageButtonQ, R.id.imageButtonR, R.id.imageButtonS, R.id.imageButtonT,
        R.id.imageButtonU, R.id.imageButtonV, R.id.imageButtonW, R.id.imageButtonX, R.id.imageButtonY, R.id.imageButtonZ
    };
    private List<ImageButton> buttonLetters = new ArrayList<ImageButton>();
```

**Edited to show solution:** I register their OnClick by doing:

```
    for (int id: BUTTON_IDS) {
        final ImageButton buttonLettersUsage = (ImageButton)findViewById(id);
        if (buttonLetters != null) {
            assert buttonLettersUsage != null;
            buttonLettersUsage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(HangmanActivity.this, " " + buttonLettersUsage.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    switch (buttonLettersUsage.getId()){
                        case R.id.imageButtonQ:
                            strGuessed = "Q";
                            break;
                        case R.id.imageButtonW:
                            strGuessed = "W";
                            break;
                        case R.id.imageButtonE:
                            strGuessed = "E";
                            break;
                        // ... Repeat for rest of buttons ...
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    btnGuessClicked(theIncorrectGuesses, theWord);
                    buttonLettersUsage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

The problem is now, I've been working on the app some more since implementing this part, and all the `buttonLettersUsage.getId()`'s have changed.

**My question is:**
Will they change at any time?
I've not put any new components onto the activity, why have they changed?
Is there a better way to find out which button has been pressed, and give a different value for `strGuessed` depending on which has been pressed?

Many thanks.

Comment: why do you have `case 2131558500:` ?

Comment: You are complicating things, use a gridview. Your cases should match the button IDs as in XML make a switch on that -- `switch(view.getId())`

Comment: 2131558500 is the ID for the ImageButtonQ, or at least it was.  It's now 2131558507.

Comment: Why don't you use `R.id.imageButtonA` instead..? If you want to change the id, click in the id, press `Shift` and `F6` and refactor the id in the given field, this will change any occurence of the id.

Comment: @Skynet I looked into GridViews before for doing this, is it possible to arrange them with out a square layout? So display with keyboard locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the numerical ids in the switch case use it as follows.

```
 switch (buttonLettersUsage.getId()){
                    case R.id.imageButtonA:
                        strGuessed = "Q";
                        break;
                    case R.id.imageButtonB:
                        strGuessed = "W";
                        break;
                    case R.id.imageButtonC:
                        strGuessed = "E";
                        break;
                    // ... Repeat for rest of buttons ...
                    default:
                        break;
                }
```

And also don't implement onClickListener like this, use your Activity to implement View.OnClickListener and then set the listener in loop as

```
buttonLettersUsage.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Where this is the context of your activity which implements the OnClickListener

Answer (score 0):

YourActivity `implements View.OnClickListener{`

then in `oncreate(){`

//add is buton

```
View buttonAdd = findViewById(R.id.add);
buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(this);}

then

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.add:
           {

      }

              break;}
```